# jQuery .remove() isn't removing (on window resize)

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I need to use jquery to add some elements on small screens and then remove them on larger screens. But for some reason, .remove() is not removing anything. All my other code is working - just not .remove(). What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var resizeflag = false;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($("#wrapper").css("overflow") === "visible") { // sample css to test if media query has fired
            if (resizeflag == false) {
                resizeflag = true;
                // add mobile menu icon
                $('#mobile-menu').before('<a id="menu-icon">Menu</a>');
                // add Economic Development to header on homepage only
                $('#homepage #site-logo').after('<div class="logo-tag">ECONOMIC DEVELOPMENT</div>');
                // add footer logo 
                $('#footer-nav').prepend('<div class="mobile-footer-logo"></div>');
            }
        } else {
            if (resizeflag == true) {
                resizeflag = false;
                // must undo these DOM manipulations if the browser is expanded again or else it will loop 
                $("a#menu-icon").remove();
                $('div.logo-tag').remove();
                $('.mobile-footer-logo').remove();
            }
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `$("a#menu-icon")`, `$('div.logo-tag')`, and `$('.mobile-footer-logo')` actually are matching elements?

Comment: If the elements exists, it's a good bet that the condition somehow fails.

Comment: I have... and they are. I'm not sure what's happening. I have a bunch of other code in that conditional that does work (I just deleted all that in my example above to focus on the remove() issue.)

Comment: I think I discovered the problem. I have to remove the elements in reverse order from when they were created. I think some of the other code was dependent on the order of other created elements, and it was getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The issue in my case was that I needed to remove the elements in reverse order. It actually had nothing to do with the .remove() function specifically -- it was that some of the elements were dependent upon other elements that were also being moved around (not shown in my truncated code above).

Hope this helps someone else who may be in this very specific situation.